Rounding.. Positioning of the \newdimen , inside or outside of the definition?
Ref:How may I round the pts from \ht?
Look at %here is the problem
Is it possible, to get the
\newdimen\mysize
        \mysize=3.7969pt

into the definition of \roundit instead of defining it before?
       \begingroup
        \catcode`\@=11
        \def\round#1{#1}
        \round{%
        \endgroup
        \csname newcount\endcsname\round@int
        \csname newcount\endcsname\round@dec
        \csname newcount\endcsname\round@places
        \csname newtoks\endcsname\round@trail
        \csname newtoks\endcsname\roundResult
        \def\round#1#2{%
          \round@places=#1\relax
          \afterassignment\round@afterint
          \round@int=#2\relax
        }
        \def\round@first#1#2\relax{#1}
        \def\round@afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
        \def\round@collect#1\relax{\roundResult={#1}}
        \def\round@afterint#1{%
          \ifx.#1%
            \afterassignment\round@afterdec
            \round@dec=%
          \else
            \ifnum\round@places>0
              \round@places=0
            \fi
            \round@afterfi{\round@intloop#1}%
          \fi
        }
        \def\round@afterdec{%
          \ifnum\round@places>0
            \expandafter\round@loop
          \else
            \ifnum\round@places=0
              \ifnum\expandafter\round@first\the\round@dec\relax>4
                \advance\round@int1
              \fi
            \fi
            \expandafter\round@intloop
          \fi
        }
        \def\round@intloop{%
          \round@trail{}%
          \loop\ifnum\round@places<0
            \round@trail\expandafter{\the\round@trail0}%
            \ifnum\round@places=-1
              \advance\round@int5
            \fi
            \divide\round@int10
            \advance\round@places1
            \ifnum\round@int=0
              \round@trail{}%
              \round@places=0
            \fi
          \repeat
          \expandafter\round@collect\the\expandafter\round@int\the\round@trail
        }
        \def\round@loop{%
          \expandafter\round@count\the\round@dec\relax
          \loop\ifnum\round@places<0
            \ifnum\round@places=-1
              \advance\round@dec5
            \fi
            \divide\round@dec10
            \advance\round@places1
          \repeat
          \expandafter\round@collect
            \the\expandafter\round@int\expandafter.\the\round@dec
        }
        \def\round@count#1{%
          \ifx\relax#1%
          \else
            \advance\round@places-1
            \expandafter\round@count
          \fi
        }
        }
        \newcount\rounder
        \newdimen\testdimen
        
         \def\roundit#1#2{%
         \rounder=#1
        \testdimen=#2
         \the\testdimen
        \round{\rounder}{\the\testdimen} %
        #2=\the\roundResult 
        }%
        \TeX
        
        \roundit{1}{\vsize}
        New vsize: \the\vsize
        
        \roundit{2}{\hsize}
        New hsize: \the\hsize
        
        \newdimen\mysize
        \mysize=3.7969pt
        \roundit{3}{\mysize}
        New mysize: \the\mysize
%here is the problem
        \mysize=4.7865pt
        \roundit{0}{\mysize}
        New mysize: \the\mysize
%here is the problem
        \bye


why \round{%         \endgroup         \csname newcount\endcsname\round@int rather than \newcount\round@int?? you are doing it at the top level so no need to dance around \outer restrictions.

you don't need \newdimen\mysize  at all for this code, just if you need that register elsewhere. For the code here you can simply use \roundit{3}{3.7969pt}

@David Carlisle
1st I took the code from another guy, without deeper understanding.  2nd I want to have the  tool to round dimens for the whole document, not just once for one value. The aim is, to have all the dimens rounded, before writing the body of the document. .

I don't understand your 2nd comment, the rounding macro you show takes one value and rounds it, it does not apply to all registers, there is no need to declare a new register for each use

@David Carlisle Ok, understood.

'another guy' being egreg?

if you put \newdimen\mydimen into the definition, every time you use the definition, you will assign \mydimen to a new dimension register. that would serve no useful purpose, so can you explain what you hope to achieve by putting it into the definition?

@cfr
I would like to keep it all together in one definition, so, if there is a way to avoid the assigments claiming a new register every time, that would be great.

@MBE the way to stop the assignments claiming a new register each time is to assign the register once at the start and then (merely) use it inside the definition. you haven't explained why that's problematic?

@cfr There is nothing problematic. I just like to have it that way.
